# Multiple subdomains, SSL on only one using port 80

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I am running a Apache2 server with three subdomains defined in separate files in /etc/apache2/sites-available

I need ONE of those subdomains to be SSL-secured on port 80 for an application to work. Port 80 is required due to circumstances out of my control. The other subdomains are also on port 80.

Now, when all subdomains are enabled in Apache the SSL-subdomain is NOT running SSL. If I disable the other subdomains SSL on the SSL-subdomain WORKS.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the way Apache listens for new connections and routes to the correct Virtual Host.

Apache will be explicitly listening for either an SSL connection or a plain-text connection, not both.

The only options would to move the secure operations to port 443 (as per spec), move the SSL-subdomain to a different IP address and bind port 80 to that, or SSL-enable the whole site with a wildcard certificate or SNI.